# NUnit testing generics with data

Tags: generics, nunit

I have the following definition of a test class.

```cs
[TestFixture(typeof(List<int>), typeof(int))]
[TestFixture(typeof(List<string>), typeof(string))]
public class SerializableListTests<TList, TValue> where TList : IList<TValue>, new()
```

I am using NUnit for testing and found examples of using the above code to create fixtures on the fly for specific types I am testing my generic class with.

The issue I have found is when I need to test data. E.g. Adding items to the list. I can't make my tests add ints as the string type tests will all fail. E.g.

```cs
public void Serializing_then_deserialize_returns_same_list()
{
     var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializableList<TList, TValue>));
     var xmlMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();

     var serializedList = new SerializableList<TList, TValue>();

     serializedList.List.Add(1);

     //Continue with deserialization and collection assert lists are equal.
}
```

Is there a way to link data used in tests to the types being used by the TestFixture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had some decent luck doing something similar with using an abstract class like `SerializableListTests<TList, TValue>` and subclassing my other testfixtures that are specific to their own type. There, you could have the base class testfixture do the adding as it would be strongly typed.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean rewriting the tests in each subclass? I could use your idea to return a subclass of the data I want to test. This would mean the tests would be written once and tested for different types/data.

Comment: I think that's a good approach, more or less what I was trying to say, but my wording isn't quite clear.